# Visual indicator of cable temperature

Tags: electrical, temperature

I have a longish extension cord I use to run power tools. Based on some rough estimates of the cable gauge, max amperage, the power use of my tools I think I should be fine if I don't run too many of them at once. But there's always a nagging doubt in the back of my head, "if I did get careless and connected too many things one day, would I know?".

As I understand it, the main failure mode resulting from overloading an extension cord is that it would heat up. Whenever I get suspicious I can walk over and feel the cable. But is there a way I can have a visual indicator of the cable temperature, so that I can tell at a glance without having to feel it?

And yes, I know that one visual indicator would be the rubber coating melting and a raging fire consuming the wall. I'm looking more for an early warning type deal :)

Comment: Please tell us cable gauge, cable length, type of tool and its nameplate draw (watts or amps). If you aren't in North America on 110v, please note that as well.

Comment: Your problem, by the way, is voltage drop, which causes your tool to draw more amps which burns out the motor.

Comment: Check your manual, they may specify minimum for extension cords, some may say not to use one. Since they make the tool they should know something about it.

Comment: Most human eyes cannot see temperature changing, would need a temperature sensor for that.  If using an extension I prefer to use one at least gauge bigger(smaller number) than what the house circuit is using.   For human eyes your last paragraph is about the only tell, the melting, the flames, and smoke.

Comment: I use simple heat test. If cord is getting hot, it is a problem.

Comment: Don’t coil the cord. If it does heat up, it needs air to cool

Comment: Not what you requested, but I use a “safety box” on the user end of the cord. Has an overload switch and the other  (residual current detector) switch , and four outlets. Then all things can be plugged in.

Comment: If the cord is getting hot, you're way past acceptable.   Feel the plugs/jacks. If they're too hot to hold comfortably, that's your warning sign.

Comment: The cords almost never fail it is the plug& socket that melt down in just about every case and if you are pushing any cord to 80% you are a fool. If the cord only has 1 end that is the limit of tools that are plugged in of it has 2 or 3 receptacles it is usually required to be 14 awg and this is when the plug into the wall almost always melts down. If it feels warm don’t push it as thermal run away is a real thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of adhesive thermometers available in many different temperature ranges that you could tape onto the cords for a quick reference without needing to grab a tool or touch the cable.

[image]
[image]

There are also paints that will change colors at different temperatures. Just paint the entire cord and then look for it changing color if you were concerned.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Visual temperature test.

Use a Laser infrared thermometer to measure the temperature off the cable.

Under normal conditions the extension cord should not be warm.

If you buy one that also works for HVAC, you can used it to check out your AC, or your insulation efficiency.

[image: laser]